# Subtract the date from current date javascript

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I want to subtract the pastDate with current date and check if the different is greater than 7 days. I am trying to do with momentjs but the subtract doesn't seems working my way.

```
pastDate= "2018-03-09 22:53:19";
dateFrom = moment(Date.now() - pastDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

if(dateFrom >= 7 ){
  console.log("Expiry Date");
}
```

Please help me with correct syntax.

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Comment: You are trying to do something like `1520986672165 - "2018-03-09 22:53:19"`, which is unlikely to yield a useful result, even in moment.js.